# Interdependent class definitions

Tags: c++, class, oop

## Problem

I have two classes: a 4-element vector (Vec4), and a 4x4 matrix (Mat4).
I am trying to define the multiplication operator in each class for the other:

```
class Mat4;
class Vec4;

class Vec4
{
public:
    float x, y, z, w;

    const Vec4 operator *(const Mat4& m)const
    {
        Vec4 r;
        //...
        return r;
    }
};
class Mat4
{
public:
    Mat4()
    { //... }

    union
    {
        Vec4  v[4];
        float m[4][4];
        struct
        {
            float _11, _12, _13, _14,
                  _21, _22, _23, _24,
                  _31, _32, _33, _34,
                  _41, _42, _43, _44;
        };
    };

    const Vec4 operator *(const Vec4& x)const
    {
        Vec4 r;

        //...

        return r;
    }
```

The compiler (MSVC++) chokes at Vec4::operator *, spitting the error
*C2027: use of undefined type 'Mat4'*

As you can see, I've declared both classes before their respective definitions as

```
class Mat4;
class Vec4;
```

Any advice on how I can have this operator without causing these race issues would be very appreciated.

Comment: Just have the signatures for the methods in the classes and the implementations in another file

Comment: There's not much you can do with a forward declared class. Define the member functions outside of the class definition where the definitions of both classes are visible.

Comment: Don't make them member functions, just have the operators in their shared namespace.

Comment: Thank you jthill, that's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I didn't particularly want to declare them in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises, because you've got definition and implementation in the same file.
Try splitting the definition (prototypes) into the header file, using only pointers to the other class and put the implementation into a separate c++ file, which includes the header file AND the header of the other class.

Basically it's telling you, that it does know, that there's a Mat4 and a Vec4 class...but it doesn't know anything more about it, unless you tell it where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaring is not enough here. That tells the compiler that is a type Mat4, but nothing more. While you can use it in signatures (with pointers and references) it not possible to use it before it is defined. So you need to split the declaration and definition in separate files.